# Is it possible to import a bundled webpack and library separately using webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack, umd

I'm trying to build a module which uses d3, but I don't want to bundle d3 with that module and, crucially, I don't want to have to bind d3 to the window. The module is to be installed on another project with npm as a git dependency. On the module I have a set up something like this:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: '[name].min.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  externals: [
    {
      "d3": {
        root: "d3"
      }
    }
  ]
```

and in the project it's installed onto I want something like this:

```
import d3 from 'd3'
import example from 'example'
```

However, that only works if I also do this:

```
import d3 from 'd3'
window.d3=d3
import example from 'example'
```

Is it possible to use both modules without touching the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
  externals: [
    {
      "d3": {
        root: "d3"
      }
    }
  ]
```

to

```
  externals: [
    {
      "d3": {
        commonjs: "d3"
      }
    }
  ]
```

[Descried in the doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals). by setting to `root`, The library should be available as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Because the two modules exist separately, they each have their own closure. The only place to share a 3rd dependency is a scope external to both, traditionally global scope.
You can practice dependency injection.

So, instead of

```
module.exports = function do_a_thing() {
  // use d3 here
}
```

You do

```
module.exports = function do_a_thing_generator(d3) {
  return function do_a_thing() {
    // use d3 here
  }
}
```

Then, eventually

```
import d3 from 'd3'
import exampleInit from 'example'

const example = exampleInit(d3)
```